# Why ionic tabs are not rendered properly?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic(although I have some knowledge of angularJs). I am facing problem in ion-tabs. Following is my code :-

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    
    $stateProvider
        
        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'   
      },
                'other@home': {
                    template: "Hello World! I am other-11."
                },
                'other': {
                    template: "Hello World! I am other 12."
                }
            }
        })
        
        // nested list with custom controller
        .state('home.list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
            }
        })
        
        // nested list with just some random string data
        .state('home.paragraph', {
            url: '/paragraph',
            template: '<ion-view view-title="paragraph">I could sure use a drink right now.</ion-view>'
        })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="partial-home.html">
  <ion-view view-title="def" hide-nav-bar="false" class="padding padding-vertical"> 
   <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon ion-home"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-email"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-person"></button>
   </ion-nav-buttons>
   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="list" icon="icon ion-home" href="#/home/list">
     <ion-nav-view name="list"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="paragraph" icon="icon ion-heart" href="#/home/paragraph">
     <ion-nav-view name="paragraph"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
   </ion-tabs>
  </ion-view>
 </script>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="partial-home-list.html">
  <ion-view view-title="list">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="dog in dogs">{{ dog }}</li>
   </ul>
  </ion-view>
 </script>
  
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
   <button class="button button-icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
   <button class="button button-icon ion-search"></button>
   <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-email"></button>
   <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-person"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
 </ion-nav-bar>
 <ion-nav-view>
 </ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

It renders following output :-[image]

Following are the problems, that I am facing :-
1)   Although, tabs are appearing, but when I click on individual tab, it's internal content is not getting populated with current code(that I have posted) and navbar title is also not changing, in spite of view-title property being set in each child state template.

2)   In `partial-home.html` template in html code, I want navbar to have some extra buttons in it, but those buttons are also not getting shown.

3)   However, when I change `partial-home.html`, to something given below(I have removed name property from ion-nav-view),

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partial-home.html">
  <ion-view view-title="def" hide-nav-bar="false" class="padding padding-vertical"> 
   <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon ion-home"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-email"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-person"></button>
   </ion-nav-buttons>
   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="list" icon="icon ion-home" href="#/home/list">
     <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="paragraph" icon="icon ion-heart" href="#/home/paragraph">
     <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
   </ion-tabs>
  </ion-view>
 </script>
```

then, tab contents are appearing properly, when I click on individual tab, but tab content appears behind navbar, as shown in image given below :-
[image]

I don't know, where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi..can you give a plunker/codepen with the above code?

Comment: Hello @varunaaruru, I am unknown to plunker/codepen. Can you create the same, if possible ?

Comment: i dont know why you are using that complex structure to create and navigate tabs.. checkout this plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/B9ORrv/

Answer (score 1):

1. Dont use `script` tags to create different tab pages . I suggest you to download starter tabs template and look into that

> Ionic start appname tabs

2. for `navbar` buttons
   include this code in the page where you want the buttons.

`

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">doSomething</button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>
```

> The side to place the buttons in the ionNavBar. Available sides:
>   primary, secondary, left, and right.

3. If content goes behind navigation bar, write this in `<ion-content>`

`<ion-content has-header="true">`

Comment: Can you let me know, why <ion-nav-buttons> is not working in my code ? My implementation is also quite like your implementation.